# Numerical solution of linear Schroedinger ODE with almost-normal Hamiltonian matrix

Tags: na.numerical-analysis

I am calculating numerical solutions of time-dependent Schroedinger equation

$\frac{d\Psi}{dt} = - i H \Psi$

where $\Psi$ is an $N$-element complex vector and $H$ is an $N \times N$ complex matrix, which is ``almost normal''. That is, $H = H_0 + i D$, where $H_0$ is normal (and often Hermitian), $D$ is Hermitian but does not commute with $H_0$, and $||D|| \ll ||H_0||$. The dimension $N$ is betwen 30 and 200.

So far, I have been using a 4-th order Runge-Kutta specialised for linear ODEs (taken from [Zingg and Chisholm](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.120.3303&rep=rep1&type=pdf)). However, the accuracy is not as good as I'd like, probably due to strong oscillations arising from the $H_0$ part. Is there a better method out there? I'd prefer one which would not require the calculation of $e^{-iH\tau}$ ($\tau$ - time-step of the ODE solver).

EDIT: more data about the problem:

The eigenvalues of $H_0$ are literally random, as $H_0 = h + diag(dE_i)$, where $dE_i ~ N(0,\sigma)$ or $dE_i \sim L(\alpha,\sigma)$. Matrix $h$ has eigenvalues of the order of unity, and $L(\alpha,\sigma)$ is the symmetric Levy alpha-stable distribution (each diagonal value of $H_0$ is perturbed by an independent distr.) with scale parameter $\alpha \in (0,2)$ and strength $\sigma$. $D$ has eigenvalues of the order of 0.1. I choose the time step to be of the order of $0.01/E_\text{max}$, where $E_\text{max}$ is the maximum absolute value of real or imaginary part of any eigenvalue of $H$.

So in short, $H$ can be nasty :(

Comment: Are both H_0 and D explicitly time dependent? If H_0 is time independent, then you could diagonalize it once and for all at the start of your calculation and use the interaction picture.

Comment: Additionally, do you know anything about the eigenvalues of D? The sign will determine whether the solution grows or decays, which might be relevant to cooking up a better numerical method.

Comment: @Jonathan $H_0$ is time-independent. But then my perturbation becomes time-dependent, won't it simply move the oscillations to another place in the calculation?

$D$ has only negative eigenvalues, so it should lead to a decay. Funnily, for some forms of $H_0$ the Runge-Kutta algorithm I use now blows up anyway.

Comment: @Jonathan Do you think that using the split-operator approach would help? I mean the approach in http://www.pci.uni-heidelberg.de/tc/usr/andreasm/academic/handouthtml/node13.html

Comment: What are the smallest and the largest eigenvalues of $H$ and what are the norm and the smoothness of $D$ and the time interval?

Comment: @fedja I added more info about the problem to the question. Thx.

Comment: And why do you want high precision if, strictly speaking, you don't even know what your matrix is (i.e., what you get is influenced more by the uncertainty and imperfection in the simulation of random variables than by the computation error)? I assume that there is no stupid mistake in the program, of course. In other words, what exactly are you looking for in your results?

Comment: @fedja I am averaging the outcome of the evolution of a quantum system (i.e. some quantities calculated from the solution of the above ODE) over the noise realisations. But blow-ups of the evolution blow up my average :(

Comment: @fedja I *know* that I shouldn't get increasing $L^2$ norm of the solution, because all eigenvalues of $H$ have negative imaginary parts. But I do, so I think this is due to ODE solver errors.

Comment: I see. What happens if you just forget about fancy things like Runge-Kutta and do the trivial Euler? I mean, it may be an approximation precision issue but it may also be some trivial programming error issue, so it would be nice to exclude the latter first. With Euler, you can easily estimate the worst possible norm deterioration at each step: it is just $e^{\tau^2\|H\|^2}$ where $\tau$ is the step, so after time $T$, you can get the growth $e^{\tau T\|H\|^2}$ at worst. It would really be nice to know how long the time period you use is to bound the simulation error with confidence.

Comment: @fedja It's of the order of 1E2, and $||H||^2$ can be even 1000.


Comment: The last question is how smooth is your D (or just what it is). Runge-Kutta is not great if the derivatives of D grow very fast in norm and you'll still have to choose a smaller step in that case. Sorry for being so inquisitive but I prefer to find exactly what the setup is before saying anything :)

Comment: @fedja $D$ is also  a matrix. The whole ODE is linear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should really be a comment, but it is too long.

Since Euler is out of question on such a long interval, my next suggestion would be to try to run the 3rd order Runge-Kutta about which I am pretty certain that it is not screwed up anywhere. The recursion step is 
$$
\begin{aligned}
x(t+\tau)&=
\cr
&x(t)
\cr
+&\frac \tau 6[H(t)+4H(t+\frac\tau 2)+H(t+\tau)]x(t)
\cr
+&\frac{\tau^2}6[H(t)^2+2H(t+\tau)H(t+\frac\tau 2)]x(t)
\cr
+&\frac{\tau^3}{6}H(t)^3x(t)
\end{aligned}
$$ 
(of course, you should never multiply matrices, only a matrix by a vector and you should pay attention to the order of matrix multiplication in the third term; I leave the obvious optimizations to you).

Try to compare the results with what you get from your 4th order Runge-Kutta. The maximal step for this 3rd order method would be $10^{-4}$ if you want to get anything meaningful in your setting (if you can afford $10^{-5}$, it would be much better). Let us know what you see. If this method exhibits slower norm growth than the 4th order one, something is screwed up in the programming. If it blows up even faster, it may, indeed, be a precision problem.

Comment: Sorry, my $H$ is yours $-iH$, so put all $i$'s accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. My $H$ is time-independent, so I can ignore the order of multiplication.

Comment: In that case what prevents you from forgetting all that Runge-Kutta stuff altogether and just using the standard Taylor expansion of the exponent with as many terms as you wish (6-7 should be more than  enough)? I mean use $x(t+s)=x(t)-isHx(t)-\frac 12s^2H^2x(t)+\frac{i}6s^3H^3x(t)+\dots$. It is not overly computationally intensive (just a 7 matrix by vector multiplications at each step) and if you choose $s\|H\|<0.1$, you should be completely fine. Runge-Kutta is mainly there to accomodate for time dependency of the matrix.

Comment: @fedja Indeed, why didn't I think about it earlier?

Comment: @fedja Would you mind editing the answer to include your last comment? it solved my problem.